# Yet more gauge group nonsense: $D3$? $Q8$? $Z8$?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, yang-mills

This'll probably make me look like a total idgit, but I have a new question in the same vein as mine about $SU(4)$, but this time without any guesses.

I've looked a bit into groups, and it looks like there are several "weird" ones, which don't seem to be incompatible with gauge theory, ones that catch my interest being $D(3)$, $Z(8)$, and $Q(8)$. How would those charges interact and neutralize? What about the behavior of their hypothetical gauge bosons?

I fully admit I could be reading into this totally incorrectly, and that i'm positing hard to calculate, or even pointless, hypotheticals.

Comment: What are these groups?

Comment: I might suggest, seeing as you've asked about this prior, looking into the text "Group theory in a nutshell for Physicists" by A. Zee. This might help you see how a groups structure leads to the mathematics in physical theories. I have a copy myself though I haven't read too much of it at the present moment. I'd also suggest that even if you and a select few know the groups in question, you should still define what groups these are to make it more accessible to others.

Comment: @doetoe I believe $D(n)$ is the dihedral group of symmetries of an n-gon, $Z(n) =\frac{Z}{nZ}$ is the quotient group of integers modulo n. Q is a multiplicative group of quaternions I'm unfamiliar with (the group itself that is).

Answer (score 3):

Big fan of gauge group nonsense. These finite group gauge theories are topological, so they don't have gauge bosons in the same way theories like electromagnetism do. They make for some interesting topological phases though, and may be useful for quantum computation some day, check this paper out https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021 .

Comment: Huh, a fellow nonsense enjoyer. I'll give the paper a good look!

Comment: @QuinnJackson Here's another you might like https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01853 , since you were asking about SU(4) also